# Insert variable name into a string dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, string, variable-names

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
s = "blah blah start=0 length=10"
```

and i have two variables named `start = 0` and `length = 100`.
Now, I want to form a new string (or replace the existing string) with:

```
s = "blah blah start="+str(start)+" length="+str(length)
```

but I want to do it dynamically, e.g. using the `replace()` method on string `s` or something similar and not by typing the above code by hand. That is, I want to form a new string with strings and variable names using python code. The string `s` changes quite often, as it is a url.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it using a simple function

```
def change_blah_str(nstart, nlength):
    return f'blah blah start= {nstart} length= {nlength}'
```

I hope you like it

Comment: The string `s` changes every so often. That' s why I need something like replacing the fixed values with the variable names using a method. I don't want to type again the new string in the method you propose. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You don't have to type it again, you just have to do:
change_blah_str(10, 20)
change_blah_str(15, 25)
change_blah_str(40, 2)
change_blah_str(53, 4)